# Where's the list of TLD that are converted to link in SMS?

Tags: applications, sms, url

When you send an SMS/Text, the Messaging app converts to clickable link certain patterns of text, when it matches a URL.

[image: SMS link conversion]

Of course I can use the Android emulator to emulate SMS messages and check what [top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) (TLD) are converted to link.
But I was curious and wanted to know the complete list. I have searched the source code of the
[stock Android app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/) and even other projects ([QKSMS](https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms)) but found nothing.

P.S. When you prefix the URL with 'http://' all TLD are converted to link.
Update: My first test (see screenshot) corresponds to Android 7. I've checked that Android 9 recognizes new TLDs.

Comment: There may be an alternative way to check that does not need pre-configured TLD lists: just send it to the configured DNS server.

Comment: @Robert Are you suggesting that the Messaging app just checks the domains? But in my example the domains are inexistent though they are correctly recognized.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, at some point in the dependency tree, one of the hundreds of the imported libraries will import `com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName`. That library contains https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/guava/+/refs/heads/master/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java

That has an encoded version of Mozilla's https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat